# Magnific popup close when i click on ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magnific-popup

Please help, when I click the link and a popup will show up.  When I then click on the content page block, the popup will close suddenly.

I already tired to add `modal: true`, and this works, but I cannot close the popup so I need another solution. please thanks in advance.

```
<a class="simple-ajax-popup-align-top" href="htmlcontent.html">Popup</a> 


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.simple-ajax-popup-align-top').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax',
        alignTop: false,
        overflowY: 'scroll',
        preloader: true,
        midClick: true,
        closeOnContentClick: false,
        enableEscapeKey: true,
        showCloseBtn: false,
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
        callbacks: {
          close: function() {
            // nothing
          }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, solved it by using:

```
modal:true,
```

instead of:

```
closeOnContentClick: false,
```

or

```
set closeOnBgClick: false instead of modal:true
```

[For more information click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600430/magnific-popup-popup-disappearing-on-click)

Comment: Thanks you so much, but I already tested all your solution but still doesn't work. I put modal: true the popup can not close by clicking on background or try to add CloseButton still no work, even close button didn't show up

Comment: @TAWAN I have updated my answer, So you can get solution.I hade same problem with this but I sort out with this.If you still not get out from it.Please check another code.Thanx

Comment: or for close from Jquery var mgObj=$('your-selecter').magnificPopup({
   // you options
});

// code to close pop up on clicking a button
$(document).on('click','button',function(){
    if(mgObj)
    {
        mgObj.close();
    }
});